# l3keys and recursive commands

Tags: expl3, recursion

I am trying to create an `l3keys` list called `mykeys` which is used to control the behaviour of the command `mycommand:n`. Initially, it is just the identity. Setting `command=\textit` should change it into `\textit` (composed with identity). In general, setting `command=\foo` should redefine `mycommand:n` to become `#1` ↦ `\foo{mycommand:n{#1}}`.
However, as it is now, it fails quite miserably. **Is it possible to make this work?**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \identity:n #1 { #1 }


\keys_define:nn { mykeys }
{
    command .multichoice:,
    command / none .code:n = {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \mycommand:n \identity:n %this resets \mycommand:n
                                               %to become the identity
    },
    command / unknown .code:n = {
        \cs_set:Npx \mycommand:n ##1
        {
            #1 { \mycommand:n { ##1 } }
        }
    }
}

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=none }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\mycommand:n{test1} % should produce test1

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=\textit }

\mycommand:n{test2} % should produce \textit{test2}

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=\textbf }

\mycommand:n{test3} % should produce \textbf{\textit{test3}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't x-expand a latex2e font command as it will blow up and you can't x-expand an expl3 defined command as it's typically `\protected`, you will want to do the equivalent of `\let\savedmycommand\mycommand \def\mycommand##1{{#1{\savedmycommand{##1}}`

Comment: I experimented with that a lot, but was unable to make it work. Eventually I decided to make my MWE as minimal as possible and see what people would suggest.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even writing what you just wrote (that is, plain TeX commands inside `expl3`) does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh no it wouldn't work as is for a start you'd have to generate a new name each time to save the previous state, but I may post a version using expansion later if egreg not done it by then (I was driving home, I thought he'd have done it by now:-)

Comment: I'm obviously missing something: why not `command .code:n = \cs_set_eq:NN \mycommand:n #1`? One could extend that to have a single-token test, _etc._ (though my experience is that you want to avoid 'magic value' keys).

Comment: @JosephWright For my purpose, it is of great importance that commands can be stacked this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not particularly keen on the interface, but here I'd store the commands for application in sequence

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__mycommand_cmds_seq
\tl_new:N \l__mycommand_tmp_tl

\keys_define:nn { mykeys }
  {
    command .code:n = 
      {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} { none }
          { \seq_clear:N \l__mycommand_cmds_seq }
          { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__mycommand_cmds_seq {#1} }
      }
  }
\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command = none }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mycommand_main:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l__mycommand_tmp_tl {#1}
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__mycommand_cmds_seq
        {
          \tl_set:Nx \l__mycommand_tmp_tl
            { \exp_not:n {##1} { \exp_not:V \l__mycommand_tmp_tl } }
        }
    \exp_args:NV \group_end:
    \l__mycommand_tmp_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \mysetup { +m } { \keys_set:nn { mykeys } {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand { m }
  { \mycommand_main:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mycommand{test1} % should produce test1

\mysetup{command = \textit}

\mycommand{test2} % should produce \textit{test2}

\mysetup{command = \textbf}

\mycommand{test3} % should produce \textbf{\textit{test3}}

\end{document}
```

One might do a single-token/macro test as part of the keyval setting, but that is likely overkill.

One might build up the 'functional' token list during the keyval setting, but I suspect that having the sequence available for inspection might be useful in debugging.

Comment: Note that `multichoice` is intended for the case `foo = {bar,baz}` not really `foo = bar, foo = baz`, _i.e._ conceptually each time you set a key the expectation is that the new value entire 'overwrites' the older one. (I have considered though not yet implemented storing all of the 'raw' key values so one can do lookup, _etc._).

Comment: So I might as well use `choice`? It is meant for a general purpose interface where the `command` key may be used to add accents or change the font of a symbol.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

so long as the commands involved expose their implementation after a single expansion, you can do something like the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \identity:n #1 { #1 }

\cs_new:Npn\wrap_def:NN#1#2{
  \exp_after:wN\cs_set:Npn
   \exp_after:wN#2\exp_after:wN##\exp_after:wN1\exp_after:wN{
   \exp_after:wN#1\exp_after:wN{#2{##1}}}
  }





\keys_define:nn { mykeys }
{
    command .multichoice:,
    command / none .code:n = {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \mycommand:n \identity:n %this resets \mycommand:n
                                               %to become the identity
    },
    command / unknown .code:n = {
        \wrap_def:NN #1 \mycommand:n
    }
}

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=none }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\mycommand:n{test1} % should produce test1

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=\textit }


\mycommand:n{test2} % should produce \textit{test2}

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=\textbf }

\mycommand:n{test3} % should produce \textbf{\textit{test3}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is closest I think to the original implementation suggestion, but I a different strategy, more robust for commands defined via xparse or latex2e `\protect` etc where a first level expansion isn't so useful, would be just to construct a `seq` of all the commands specified so far and then generate the nested call on the fly when needed by mapping over the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing David's suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_gaussler_command_start_tl
\tl_new:N \l_gaussler_command_end_tl

\keys_define:nn { mykeys }
 {
  command .multichoice:,
  command / none .code:n =
   {
    \tl_clear:N \l_gaussler_command_start_tl
    \tl_clear:N \l_gaussler_command_end_tl
    \cs_set_protected:Nn \gaussler_thecommand:n { ##1 }
   },
  command / unknown .code:n =
   {
    \tl_put_left:Nn \l_gaussler_command_start_tl { \exp_not:N #1 \gaussler_command_open: }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_gaussler_command_end_tl { \gaussler_command_close: }
    \cs_set_protected:Nx \gaussler_thecommand:n
     {
      \tl_use:N \l_gaussler_command_start_tl
      ##1 
      \tl_use:N \l_gaussler_command_end_tl
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \gaussler_command_open: { \if_true: { \else: } \fi: }
\cs_new:Nn \gaussler_command_close: { \if_false: { \else: } \fi: }

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=none }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\gaussler_thecommand:n{test1} % should produce test1

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=\textit }

\gaussler_thecommand:n{test2} % should produce \textit{test2}

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=\textbf }

\gaussler_thecommand:n{test3} % should produce \textbf{\textit{test3}}

\keys_set:nn { mykeys } { command=none }

\gaussler_thecommand:n{test4}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick with the conditionals! :-) I was experimenting with using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, which obviously collapsed everything.

Comment: @Gaussler `\bgroup` and `\egroup` cannot be used for delimiting arguments.